# UITableView use xib to set cell,when Sliding it not smooth?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

I have use xib set the interface,when using it dosen't smooth,why?

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomerCell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        NSArray * nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MSNeedCheckCell" owner:self options:nil] ;
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
//填充cell的内容
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the following method from your init method for the class:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MSNeedCheckCell" bundle:nil]
     forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomerCell"];
```

And then, you can remove your entire `if (!cell) {` section of code since it will always return a cell.  This only loads the nib once instead of every time that you need a cell so will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Is this, quite literally, all there is to it? Or are you doing anything else (e.g. in subclassed cell, or other code that you may have omitted for the sake of brevity).

The most common source of lack of smoothness (and by smoothness, I assume you're talking about a stuttering in the UI as you scroll in your tableview) would be if you're doing anything with images in the foreground queue.

The WWDC 2012 - [211 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211) offers a wonderful, practical illustration of how to use Instruments to identify the sources of performance bottlenecks. Clearly they're focusing on a very specific design consideration there, but the Instruments tutorial is very useful. It would be good to make sure that this particular line of code is really the problem before you lose too much sleep over it.